# Showing $g \in L^1((0,1))$ given $f \in L^1((0,1))$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f \in L^1((0,1))$ and define $g$ on $(0,1)$ by

$$g(x)=\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dt$$

I need to show $g \in L^1((0,1))$

My thoughts:

Take the integral, and obtain

$$\int_0^1 g(x) dx = \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dtdx$$

Then I use the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem to conclude

$$\int_0^1 g(x) dx = \int_x^1 \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dx dt=\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)x}{t}\bigg\vert_0^1dt=\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} dt$$

which is finite thus $\int_0^1 g(x) dx$ is finite?

Comment: When interchanging the variables of integration, the endpoints of integration must change as well. (It doesn't make sense for the answer to be a function of $x$—it's just a number.)

Comment: how do I fix it? @GregMartin

Comment: I thought I changed the endpoints @GregMartin

Comment: do I consider cases where $x \in (0,1)$ and $x \not \in (0,1)$?

Comment: @GregMartin how do I take care of th $x$?

Comment: @Snoop YES I believe so!, thanks!!